# six.moves.builtins.range is not consistent in Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, portability

For a very large integer range, `xrange` (Python 2) should be used, which is renamed to `range` in Python 3. I assumed module `six` can provide a consistent why of writing.

But I found `six.moves.builtins.range` returns a list in Python 2 and an iterable non-list object in Python 3, just as the name `range` does.

Also, `six.moves.builtins.xrange` does not exist in Python 2.

Was I using the wrong function in `six`? Or does six simply not provide a solution for the `range` and `xrange` functions?

I know I can test `sys.version[0]` and rename the function accordingly. I was just looking for a "Don't Repeat Yourself" solution.

## APPEND

As mentioned by mgilson:

```
>>> import six 
>>> six.moves.range
AttributeError: '_MovedItems' object has no attribute 'range'
```

Is it something related to the version of `six`, or is there no such thing as `six.moves.range`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you just want `six.moves.range`.  Not, `six.moves.builtins.range`.

```
>>> # tested on python2.x..
>>> import six.moves as sm
>>> sm.range
<type 'xrange'>
```

The reason here is that `six.moves.builtins` is the version agnostic "builtins" module.  That just gives you access to the builtins -- it doesn't actually change what any of the builtins *are*.

Typically, I don't feel the need to introduce the external dependency in cases like this.  I usually just add something like this to the top of my source file:

```
try:
    xrange
except NameError:  # python3
    xrange = range
```

Comment: Thanks! But on my Python 2.7.4 and 3.3.1, there is such `six.moves.range`: `AttributeError: '_MovedItems' object has no attribute 'range'` for both versions. As to `external dependency` you mentioned, since `six` is already been used in other places, I just feel free to use it again.

Comment: @frozen-flame -- Did you try to re-install `six`?