# What's the difference in statements below to get a range?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

When I read the Django tickets and pull requests, I find they have following changes:

They want to get a range about page numbers, And change from

```
return range(1, self.num_pages + 1) # 1
```

to:

```
return six.moves.range(1, self.num_pages + 1) # 2
```

then:

```
 return list(six.moves.range(1, self.num_pages + 1)) # 3
```

I am confusing what's difference  between 1 and 3?  And why not just this, is there any difference with 3?

```
 return list(range(1, self.num_pages + 1)) # 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Python documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#module-six.moves):

> Python 3 reorganized the standard library and moved several functions
>   to different modules. Six provides a consistent interface to them
>   through the fake `six.moves` module.

In the same page, it tells us that `six.moves.range()` calls `xrange()` for Python 2 and `range()` for Python 3. `xrange()` is very similar to `range()`, except that it returns an `xrange` object rather than a `list`. Thus the `list()` around the call to make it into a `list`.

It seems that the whole point of the change was to make the code work with both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: Is there any difference with 3 and 4? all return a list  in python2 and python3.

Comment: Yejing...you should read the documentation that he put in there. xrange and range in python2 are not the same. range in python3 is xrange. xrange is more efficient for larger sets because it only generates the "list" bit by bit, not all at once.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have read the doc.  `xrange` is more efficient than `range` in python2.  But is  `list(xrange(some_num))`   more efficient than `list(range(some_num))` in python2 ?  or are they same?

Comment: Yejing, it looks like the six module allows the runtime to dynamically choose xrange (if python2 is running), or range (if python3 is running). so you win either way. It's more efficient and calling that import lets it always happen.

Answer (score 1):

`range` in Python 2.X is constructs a new list.  So, for example:

```
range(4) == [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

`xrange` in Python 2.X is an generator that lazily yields values equivalent to what would be returned by `range` without any of the memory overhead.

Python 3.X got rid of `range` with replaced it with `xrange`.  The behavior of `xrange` is generally more efficient, but if you really need to construct a list using range you'll have to explicitly iterate it or use the `list` constructor.

`range` in Python 2.X returns a list.  In Python 3.X:

```
>>> type(range(4))
<class 'range'>
```

To explicitly create a list with range in Python 3 just do:

```
list(range(4)) == [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Or

```
my_list = [ x for x in range(4) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this SO question may offer some guidance: [six.moves.builtins.range is not consistent in Python 2 and Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086804/six-moves-builtins-range-is-not-consistent-in-python-2-and-python-3), it certainly did for me. It looks like they made the change for efficiency sake.